# Passing Data from JQuery To MVC3 Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have a requirement where am doing search based on the users input and users can dynamically add the search row

```
<tr id="tblNewContentRow">
<td>
@Html.TextBox("txtNewAttributes", "", new { @class = "alphaonly", style = "width: 155px;" })
</td>
<td>
@{@Html.DropDownList("ddlNewValues", Model.OperandsMaxList, new { style = "height: 20px;" })
}
</td>
<td colspan="2">
@Html.TextBox("txtNewValues", "", new { @class = "numbersonly", style = "width: 250px;" })
 </td>
</tr>
```

and ADD button generates the similar row below this row dynamically(i used Jquery) as much rows as user wants.

When the user hits submit i want to query this attributes(textbox,dropdown,textbox) for list in Database. i can pass this data using the Ajax call.

My question is how to send those multiple values in json to controller so ican easily map and retrieve values

Comment: have you tried google ? http://bit.ly/WPiAJc , Use jquery Ajax method to post the values to the server.

Comment: i know how to call controller but how to frame this is JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

var data=('#form_id').serializeArray();

Then send this ' data' as attribute and expect string[] type in controller. The whole data will be passed to the controller

Cheers
PHANI*